# PHP optimize multiple update and select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php API where i am checking different conditions and based on that, i am fetching the count of the row and updating the count in the same table.

**Below are the Conditions i am writing the query:**  (Note: 1 user can have multiple campaigns)

1) For a given user(Uid), for a particular campaign whose type = **Impression**, i am getting the Impression count and updating the same in table

2) For a given user(Uid), for a particular campaign whose type = **Action** i am getting the Action count and updating the same in table

```
//To get the Impression/Action/Lead count
        $Impressionarr = [];
        $Actionarr = [];

//IMPRESSION COUNT
            $imp_qry = "select count(*) as ImpressionCount from ClicksAndImpressions where Uid = 101642 and CampaignID =100 and Type='Impression' ;";
            $impData = $this->getClicksAndImpressionsTable()->CustomQuery($imp_qry);
            if($impData[0]['ImpressionCount'] != '' || $impData[0]['ImpressionCount'] !=NULL ){
                $impr_update = "UPDATE ClicksAndImpressions SET ImpressionCount = ". $impData[0]['ImpressionCount'] ." where Uid = 101642 and CampaignID =100 ;";

            }else{
                echo '----not Present';
            }

//Impression count
              foreach($impData as $key=>$data)
              {
                  $data['ImpressionCount'];
                  $Impressionarr[] = $data; 
              }

//ACTION COUNT
            $action_qry = "select count(*) as ActionCount from ClicksAndImpressions where Uid = 101617 and CampaignID =81 and Type = 'Action';";
            $actionData = $this->getClicksAndImpressionsTable()->CustomQuery($action_qry);
            if($actionData[0]['ActionCount'] != '' || $actionData[0]['ActionCount'] !=NULL ){
                $action_update = "UPDATE ClicksAndImpressions SET ActionCount = ". $actionData[0]['ActionCount'] ." where Uid = 101617 and CampaignID =81 ;";
                $actionData = $this->getClicksAndImpressionsTable()->CustomUpdate($action_update); //print_r($actionData);exit;
            }else{
                echo '----not Present';
            }


//Action count
                foreach($actionData as $key=>$data)
                {
                    $data['ActionCount'];
                    $Actionarr[] = $data; 
                }

//Trying to combine the 3 arrays- but 2nd and 3rd not merging into 1st
$combine = array_merge($CampaignDetailsarr,$Impressionarr,$Actionarr);
```

1) Can the above duplicates - either in Update query or multiple for loops be avoided. if so how to optimize the above as per my conditions

ie) For

```
if( Uid = 123 for some campaignId = 11 and if type is 'Impression')

      -> Update query for impression


else if(Uid = 123 for campaignId= 22 and if type = 'something else')

    -> Update query for something else
```

2) I already have one array 1. I need to merge my 2 new arrays (Impressionarr[], Actionarr[]) into the 1st one, but below is how im getting.

**Expected:**

[image]

**Coming as:**

[image]

Comment: I would start with refactoring your code with ORM like Doctrine (Eloquent is more tricky outside of Laravel). https://www.doctrine-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably speed it up by creating a stored procedure in your database and calling that with the required data. From what I can see, most of the logic you have to do can be done in the stored procedure.

Comment: For the queries I will try stored procedure. But for handling different conditions I needed an idea, instead of using multiple for loops. And also for the array merge , could you suggest how to merge the 2nd and 3rd array ...Why array_merge is not merging

Comment: Well, you can pass the relevant data you base you conditional checks on into the stored procedure and handle logic in there. For your array you probably wan't to use array_merge (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). If you have more complicated array structures array_merge_recursive or a manual approach of itterating the arrays and combining them might be a better option.

Comment: I thought it's a bad practice to use stored procedures nowadays since it's very hard to test.

Comment: What's ur views or suggestions on this code @Denis. Any way can u update the optimize code here ?

Comment: @DenisKovzelyuk: Some people have loved them since the start and some hated them. They do have their place though and I think, like with most technologies, it's a matter of using them when they make sense.